# Cant scroll from last item to first item in Infinite View pager Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager

How to scroll from last item to first item in Infinite ViewPager Android.
what are the possible ways to do this ? I tried almost everything and didnt find anything from Google yet.

```
public void setAdapter(PagerAdapter adapter) {
    super.setAdapter(adapter);
    setCurrentItem(0);
}
@Override
public void setCurrentItem(int item) {
    setCurrentItem(item, true);
}
@Override
public void setCurrentItem(int item, boolean smoothScroll) {
    if (getAdapter().getCount() == 0) {
        super.setCurrentItem(item, smoothScroll);
        return;
    }
    item = getOffsetAmount() + (item % getAdapter().getCount());
    super.setCurrentItem(item, smoothScroll);
}
@Override
public int getCurrentItem() {
    if (getAdapter().getCount() == 0) {
        return super.getCurrentItem();
    }
    int position = super.getCurrentItem();
    if (getAdapter() instanceof InfinitePagerAdapter) {
        InfinitePagerAdapter infAdapter = (InfinitePagerAdapter) getAdapter();
        return (position % infAdapter.getRealCount());
    } else {
        return super.getCurrentItem();
    }
}
private int getOffsetAmount() {
    if (getAdapter().getCount() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (getAdapter() instanceof InfinitePagerAdapter) {
        InfinitePagerAdapter infAdapter = (InfinitePagerAdapter) getAdapter();
        return infAdapter.getRealCount() * 100;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried this https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager